# Coloring the area between two specific lines in R

Tags: r, data-visualization

I am trying to fill colors based on conditions, if x value is greater than y , one color, and vice versa. I have a step chart of two lines bases on that I need to show color coding.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

[image]

```
 geom_ribbon(data=df, aes(x = datetime, 
                                ymin=min_value-10,
                                ymax=min_value-20,
                                fill=x > y)
```

I am using **geom ribbon** somehow color coding is not working as expected with the datetime series.
one color is completely overshadowing the other and not working as per logic.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem a while ago.  From memory, the problem was that the `fill` aesthetic cannot change within a geom layer.  My solution was to partition the dataset and plot each partiction separately.

In the absence of test data...

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(
  x=seq(0, 1, 0.05), 
  ymin=1, 
  ymax=2, 
  z=x < 0.26 | x > 0.74
) %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_ribbon(data=d %>% filter(z), aes(x=x, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, fill="red")) +
  geom_ribbon(data=d %>% filter(!z), aes(x=x, ymin=ymin, ymax=ymax, fill="blue"))
```

[image]